# How to copy child items to destination when destination folder exists?

Tags: powershell

i have two folders "C:\Source1" and "C:\Source2". Im using powershell to copy items from these two folders to single destination folder

```
Copy-Item "C:\Source1" "C:\Destination" -recurse -force
```

this creates a "C:\Destination" folder and copies all files & directories from "Source1" as expected. Note it does not create "Source1" folder under "C:\Destination"

Now i run the following command

```
 Copy-Item "C:\Source2" "C:\Destination" -recurse -force
```

This time instead of coping all the child items under "Source2" it creates a new folder "Source2" under "C:\Destination" and copies all child files & directories under "C:\Destination\Source2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell the cmdlet that you want to copy the folder's *content* instead of the folder itself:

```
Copy-Item 'C:\Source2\*' 'C:\Destination' -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: i had to use 'C:\Source2\\*' instead of C:\Source\\*.*'